# Unable to build library for iOS (arm) because SSE, AVX, etc flags get set by configure, libtool

Tags: clang, tesseract, configure, libtool, libtool-xcode

I'm trying to get Tesseract to build for iOS (and macOS) but am running into errors when building for the `arm-apple-darwin64` target.

[Here's the Makefile](https://github.com/hamchapman/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/blob/macos-support/TesseractOCR/Makefile).

The `configure` commands are run with this command:

```
./configure --host=arm-apple-darwin64 --prefix=`pwd` --enable-shared=no --disable-graphics
```

and then the `make` command is run with this:

```
make -sj8
```

However, I'm getting errors about SSE, AVX, and similar. I can see in the `libtool` command that's being run that some flags including `-DAVX`, `-DAVX2`, `-DSSE4_1`, etc are being set, but I don't think they should be for the `arm-apple-darwin64` target, as far as I know.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? What makes it more confusing is that this exact `Makefile` used to work for me just fine, but it has started to fail me just recently and I can't think what's changed.

This is (most of) the error output (it was too large to copy and paste in its entirety):

```
cd /Users/ham/projects/swift/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/TesseractOCR/tesseract-ocr/ios/arm-apple-darwin64 && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -sj8 && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make install
Making all in src/arch
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../../src/arch -I../.. -DNDEBUG -I../../../../src/ccstruct -I../../../../src/ccutil -I../../../../src/viewer -I/Users/ham/projects/swift/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/TesseractOCR/tesseract-ocr/ios/arm-apple-darwin64/ -L/Users/ham/projects/swift/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/TesseractOCR/ios/lib -Qunused-arguments -arch arm64 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=10.0 -O2 -fembed-bitcode -I/Users/ham/projects/swift/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/TesseractOCR/leptonica/ios/arm-apple-darwin64/include/leptonica -msse4.1 -I/Users/ham/projects/swift/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/TesseractOCR/tesseract-ocr/ios/arm-apple-darwin64/ -L/Users/ham/projects/swift/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/TesseractOCR/ios/lib -Qunused-arguments -arch arm64 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=10.0 -O2 -Wno-deprecated-register -std=c++14 -MT libtesseract_sse_la-intsimdmatrixsse.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libtesseract_sse_la-intsimdmatrixsse.Tpo -c ../../../../src/arch/intsimdmatrixsse.cpp -o libtesseract_sse_la-intsimdmatrixsse.o
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../../src/arch -I../.. -DNDEBUG -I../../../../src/ccstruct -I../../../../src/ccutil -I../../../../src/viewer -I/Users/ham/projects/swift/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/TesseractOCR/tesseract-ocr/ios/arm-apple-darwin64/ -L/Users/ham/projects/swift/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/TesseractOCR/ios/lib -Qunused-arguments -arch arm64 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=10.0 -O2 -fembed-bitcode -I/Users/ham/projects/swift/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/TesseractOCR/leptonica/ios/arm-apple-darwin64/include/leptonica -mavx -I/Users/ham/projects/swift/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/TesseractOCR/tesseract-ocr/ios/arm-apple-darwin64/ -L/Users/ham/projects/swift/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/TesseractOCR/ios/lib -Qunused-arguments -arch arm64 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=10.0 -O2 -Wno-deprecated-register -std=c++14 -MT libtesseract_avx_la-dotproductavx.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libtesseract_avx_la-dotproductavx.Tpo -c ../../../../src/arch/dotproductavx.cpp -o libtesseract_avx_la-dotproductavx.o
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../../src/arch -I../.. -DNDEBUG -I../../../../src/ccstruct -I../../../../src/ccutil -I../../../../src/viewer -I/Users/ham/projects/swift/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/TesseractOCR/tesseract-ocr/ios/arm-apple-darwin64/ -L/Users/ham/projects/swift/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/TesseractOCR/ios/lib -Qunused-arguments -arch arm64 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=10.0 -O2 -fembed-bitcode -I/Users/ham/projects/swift/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/TesseractOCR/leptonica/ios/arm-apple-darwin64/include/leptonica -mavx2 -I/Users/ham/projects/swift/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/TesseractOCR/tesseract-ocr/ios/arm-apple-darwin64/ -L/Users/ham/projects/swift/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/TesseractOCR/ios/lib -Qunused-arguments -arch arm64 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=10.0 -O2 -Wno-deprecated-register -std=c++14 -MT libtesseract_avx2_la-intsimdmatrixavx2.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libtesseract_avx2_la-intsimdmatrixavx2.Tpo -c ../../../../src/arch/intsimdmatrixavx2.cpp -o libtesseract_avx2_la-intsimdmatrixavx2.o
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../../src/arch -I../.. -DNDEBUG -I../../../../src/ccstruct -I../../../../src/ccutil -I../../../../src/viewer -I/Users/ham/projects/swift/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/TesseractOCR/tesseract-ocr/ios/arm-apple-darwin64/ -L/Users/ham/projects/swift/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/TesseractOCR/ios/lib -Qunused-arguments -arch arm64 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=10.0 -O2 -fembed-bitcode -I/Users/ham/projects/swift/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/TesseractOCR/leptonica/ios/arm-apple-darwin64/include/leptonica -msse4.1 -I/Users/ham/projects/swift/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/TesseractOCR/tesseract-ocr/ios/arm-apple-darwin64/ -L/Users/ham/projects/swift/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/TesseractOCR/ios/lib -Qunused-arguments -arch arm64 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=10.0 -O2 -Wno-deprecated-register -std=c++14 -MT libtesseract_sse_la-dotproductsse.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libtesseract_sse_la-dotproductsse.Tpo -c ../../../../src/arch/dotproductsse.cpp -o libtesseract_sse_la-dotproductsse.o
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../../src/arch -I../.. -DNDEBUG -I../../../../src/ccstruct -I../../../../src/ccutil -I../../../../src/viewer -DAVX -DAVX2 -DSSE4_1 -I/Users/ham/projects/swift/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/TesseractOCR/tesseract-ocr/ios/arm-apple-darwin64/ -L/Users/ham/projects/swift/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/TesseractOCR/ios/lib -Qunused-arguments -arch arm64 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=10.0 -O2 -fembed-bitcode -I/Users/ham/projects/swift/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/TesseractOCR/leptonica/ios/arm-apple-darwin64/include/leptonica -I/Users/ham/projects/swift/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/TesseractOCR/tesseract-ocr/ios/arm-apple-darwin64/ -L/Users/ham/projects/swift/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/TesseractOCR/ios/lib -Qunused-arguments -arch arm64 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=10.0 -O2 -Wno-deprecated-register -std=c++14 -MT libtesseract_arch_la-simddetect.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libtesseract_arch_la-simddetect.Tpo -c ../../../../src/arch/simddetect.cpp -o libtesseract_arch_la-simddetect.o
../../../../src/arch/dotproductavx.cpp:20:2: error: Implementation only for AVX capable architectures
../../../../src/arch/dotproductsse.cpp:19:../../../../src/arch/intsimdmatrixsse.cpp2:: 19:error2: : Implementationerror : only for SSE 4.1Implementation  capableonly  architecturesfor#error Implementation only for AVX capable architectures 

SSE 4.1 capable  ^architectures

#error Implementation only for SSE 4.1 capable architectures
 ^
../../../../src/arch/intsimdmatrixavx2.cpp:20:2: error: Implementation only for #error Implementation only for SSE 4.1 capable architecturesAVX2
 capable architectures
 ^
#error Implementation only for AVX2 capable architectures
 ^
In file included from ../../../../src/arch/dotproductavx.cpp:23:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/immintrin.h:28:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:47:5: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_emms'; did you mean '__builtin_isless'?
    __builtin_ia32_emms();
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:47:5: note: '__builtin_isless' declared here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:47:25: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 2, have 0
    __builtin_ia32_emms();
                        ^
In file included from ../../../../src/arch/dotproductsse.cpp:22:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/emmintrin.h:27:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/xmmintrin.h:27:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:47:5: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_emms'; did you mean '__builtin_isless'?
    __builtin_ia32_emms();
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:47:5: note: '__builtin_isless' declared here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:47:25: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 2, have 0
    __builtin_ia32_emms();
                        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:64:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si(__i, 0);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:64:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si(__i, 0);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:81:12: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_vec_ext_v2si'
    return __builtin_ia32_vec_ext_v2si((__v2si)__m, 0);
           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:81:12: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_vec_ext_v2si'
    return __builtin_ia32_vec_ext_v2si((__v2si)__m, 0);
           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:143:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_packsswb'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packsswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:143:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_packsswb'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packsswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:173:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_packssdw'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packssdw((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:173:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_packssdw'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packssdw((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:203:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_packuswb'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packuswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:203:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_packuswb'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packuswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:230:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckhbw'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhbw((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:230:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckhbw'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhbw((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:253:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckhwd'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhwd((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:253:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckhwd'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhwd((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:274:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckhdq'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhdq((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:274:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckhdq'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhdq((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:301:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpcklbw'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpcklbw((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:301:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpcklbw'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpcklbw((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:324:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpcklwd'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpcklwd((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:324:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpcklwd'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpcklwd((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:345:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckldq'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckldq((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:345:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckldq'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckldq((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:366:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddb'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:387:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddw'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h                  ^:
366:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddb'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:408:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddd'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddd((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:387:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddw'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:430:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddsb'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddsb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:408:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddd'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddd((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:453:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddsw'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddsw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:430:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddsb'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddsb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                  ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:453:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddsw'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddsw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make[5]: *** [libtesseract_sse_la-dotproductsse.lo] Error 1
make[5]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from ../../../../src/arch/intsimdmatrixsse.cpp:25:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/emmintrin.h:27:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/xmmintrin.h:27:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:47:5: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_emms'; did you mean '__builtin_isless'?
    __builtin_ia32_emms();
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:47:5: note: '__builtin_isless' declared here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:47:25: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 2, have 0
    __builtin_ia32_emms();
                        ^
In file included from ../../../../src/arch/intsimdmatrixavx2.cpp:25:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/immintrin.h:28:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:47:5: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_emms'; did you mean '__builtin_isless'?
    __builtin_ia32_emms();
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:47:5: note: '__builtin_isless' declared here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:47:25: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 2, have 0
    __builtin_ia32_emms();
                        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:64:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si(__i, 0);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:64:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si(__i, 0);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:81:12: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_vec_ext_v2si'
    return __builtin_ia32_vec_ext_v2si((__v2si)__m, 0);
           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:81:12: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_vec_ext_v2si'
    return __builtin_ia32_vec_ext_v2si((__v2si)__m, 0);
           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:143:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_packsswb'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packsswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:143:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_packsswb'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packsswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:173:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_packssdw'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packssdw((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:173:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_packssdw'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packssdw((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:203:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_packuswb'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packuswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:203:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_packuswb'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packuswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:230:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckhbw'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhbw((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:230:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckhbw'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhbw((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:253:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckhwd'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhwd((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:253:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckhwd'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhwd((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:274:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckhdq'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhdq((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:274:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckhdq'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhdq((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                  ^
20 errors generated.
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:301:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpcklbw'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpcklbw((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:301:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpcklbw'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpcklbw((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:324:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpcklwd'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpcklwd((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:324:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpcklwd'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpcklwd((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:345:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckldq'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckldq((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                  ^
make[5]: *** [libtesseract_avx_la-dotproductavx.lo] Error 1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:345:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckldq'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckldq((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:366:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddb'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:366:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddb'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:387:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddw'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:387:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddw'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:408:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddd'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddd((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:408:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddd'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddd((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:430:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddsb'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddsb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                  ^
...
5 errors generated.
```